# AzureAD middleware breaking because of HTTP/HTTPS redirectUri issue

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm trying to set up AzureAD on a Blazor server-side app running ASP.NET Core 3.1. The configuration mirrors that of the app that the Blazor template shows up, so there's nothing exceptional about it. Here are the relevant bits from the Startup.cs file - note that there's very little more than this.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddAzureAD(opt => {
    opt.Domain = "example.com";
    opt.TenantId = "tenantId";
    opt.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    opt.ClientId = "clientId";
    opt.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
  });
```

I'm using Azure Application Gateway and I've got all my certificates installed there. Because it allows for SSL unwrapping, all requests should hit the App Gateway, unwrap and then get routed to the service running the web server wherever it lives in the backend. Certificate management being the pain it is, I'd ideally like to run the server entirely in an HTTP context within the cluster, especially since the service isn't otherwise accessible from the internet.

The Application Gateway only points inbound HTTPS requests to the service. HTTP requests are redirected to the HTTPS listener.

This is apparently a problem for the ASP.NET Core middleware. Per the configuration above, I can only set the path. This is proving a problem. The value in the redirect_uri points to http://example.com/signin-oidc. Note the protocol - I think it's using http because the middleware is picking up that HTTP isn't being used on the machine itself.

I get dropped on the Microsoft login page, I log in, it hits the redirect on App Gateway (since the redirect_uri points to http://) and redirects to https. App Gateway unwraps the SSL and the service receives the request. I've got the DevelopmentException page showing for errors and it indicates that an unhandled exception occurs while processing the request. Unfortunately, it's vague:

> Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null
> or empty. Unknown location. Exception: An error was encountered while
> handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Now, I read through some similar notes on SO about this and it was suggested that I might use the OpenId Connect OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event to intercept and set the RedirectUri value to set it to whatever I'd like.

When I update Startup.cs, I set the following instead:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
    opt.DefaultScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
  })
  .AddAzureAD(opt => {
    opt.Domain = "mydomain.net";
    opt.TenantId = "tenantId";
    opt.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    opt.ClientId = "clientId";
    opt.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
  })
  .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", opt => {
    opt.ClientId = "clientId"; //If I don't set this, I get an error it's not set
    opt.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/";
    opt.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async c => {
      c.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://{domain}/signin-oidc";
      await Task.FromResult(0);
    };
  });
```

This ideally includes the minimum amount possible to change the redirect_uri value to use "https" instead of "http". This skips the redirect, but unfortunately yields a different exception:

> Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State. Unknown location.
> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Searching around doesn't yield a whole lot of relevant ideas on this one.

If I run this entirely locally in dev and there's no https component (all HTTP), this works without issue. So it seems like the issue here is that the middleware produces http:// and the App Gateway receives https:// (after a potential redirect), which appears to break things. Setting the RedirectUri property ideally would have fixed this, but appears to mess with how the data is protected in transit.

Can anyone shed any light on how to make this scenario work? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @GovindSharma-MSFTIdentity. At this point, I haven't yet confirmed that it resolves my inquiry, but I'll update accordingly if it does.

Comment: I'm not sure why the the clue for me was here https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1012#issuecomment-255615222 I set the callback path back to \signin-oidc and it now works. It seems the call back to the server needs the auth to be reprocessed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and my solution was to:

1. set c.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri as you do to the httpS URL
2. Change the cookies to be set as secure using this

   ```
   options.NonceCookie = new CookieBuilder { 
        Name = OpenIdConnectDefaults.CookieNoncePrefix,
        HttpOnly = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
        SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
        IsEssential = true
   }
   options.CorrelationCookie = new CookieBuilder {
       SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
   }
   ```